# How do I get all the trasnactions by Email from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I want to be able to search by email (Just like it is done with MySQL) and it gives me the result  expected in MongoDb
there are two things

****1.)** I want to have aquery where i can search for everything with MongoDB and get everything vis Email**

My code is looking thus

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Transaction = require("../models/Transactions");

router.get("/get-transactionby-email/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.findById(req.params.email);
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

But I am getting this Error back at Postman:

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"john_kross2@yopmail.com\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Transactions\""
}
```

****2.)** How do i get all credits tranactions when I have colums called credit , debit and amount in the database using Node.js and Mongo DB**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work.
The code is looking thus :

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Transaction = require("../models/Transactions");

router.get("/get-transactionby-email/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find({email: req.params.email});
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.get("/get-credit-transaction/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find({email: req.params.email},{email:true,narration:true,credit:true,amount:true});
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.get("/get-debit-transaction/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }
    const trans = await Transaction.find({email: req.params.email},{email:true,narration:true,debit:true,amount:true});
    res.status(200).json(trans);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks everyone.